# How to manage content on netlify cms stored on another git repo?

Tags: content-management-system, netlify, netlify-cms, decap-cms

what changes need to be done in config file if need to manage content on netlify cms which is not stored in the same repo (maybe abc_user/cms) as it, but on a different repo (abc_user/content), also need github authentication.